# Beamer: how to create a page quite identical to this one?

Tags: beamer, numbering, text

I should create a page with beamer like that attached below. I have some issues:

1. How can I add "Pag:" on the bottom left and "DDI Dipartimento di Ingegneria Corso di fluidodinamica" on the top right?
2. How can I number the frame with the digit next to "Pag:"?

Here are the images I used:

italian flag: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9wrj0u4uofj50e5/italian_flag.png?dl=0

top horizontal line: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ebfc9mdgz5wdynh/barra_superiore_due.png?dl=0

bottom horizontal line: https://www.dropbox.com/s/22bxdhz8ev688tw/nuova_barra.png?dl=0

graph: https://www.dropbox.com/s/piysg9rokn0gpml/foto.png?dl=0

This is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[9pt,handout]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{textpos} 
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} 
\usepackage{pifont} 
\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=black} 
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black} 
\usefonttheme{structurebold} 

\title{La mia prima presentazione}
\author{Ugo Foscolo}
\date{1 ottobre 2009}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle    
\end{frame}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}[0.85,-9.5](.85\textwidth,-1cm) %La parentesi quadra contiene le coordinate xy di dove si vuole posizionare il logo. L'ascissa positiva è verso sx. L'ordinata verso l'alto.
\includegraphics[height=0.15cm,width=10cm]{barra_superiore_due}
\end{textblock*}}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}[0.85,-0.4](.85\textwidth,-1cm) %La parentesi quadra contiene le coordinate xy di dove si vuole posizionare il logo. L'ascissa positiva è verso sx. L'ordinata verso l'alto.
\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{italian_flag}
\end{textblock*}}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}[0.85,-180](.85\textwidth,-1cm) %La parentesi quadra contiene le coordinate xy di dove si vuole posizionare il logo. L'ascissa positiva è verso sx. L'ordinata verso l'alto.
\includegraphics[height=0.05cm,width=7cm]{nuova_barra}
\end{textblock*}}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Transizione di tipo bypass}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{foto}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\ding{227}] estensione allo strato limite nelle turbomacchine (Chen e Thyson):

\begin{itemize}
\item[\ding{229}] $u$ sostituita dalla velocità all'inizio della transizione $u_{t}$
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
\item[\ding{229}] $\sigma$ sostituito da un parametro che tiene conto della variazione della velocità freestream $\bar{\sigma}(u_{t}/\bar{u})$
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
\item[\ding{229}] $\bar{\sigma}\simeq const.$ per flusso accelerante (Narashima)
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
\item[\ding{229}] il modello di transizione richiede di determinare:
  \begin{itemize}
   \item[$\bullet$] il numero di Reynolds all'inizio della transizione $Re_{x,t}$
  \end{itemize}

  \begin{itemize}
   \item[$\bullet$] il parametro di produzione degli spot $\hat{n}$
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}


\end{itemize}

\end{column}
\end{columns}


\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! Please note that your question is likely to attract more interest if you can minimise your code and make it focus on the points you are asking about. Try replacing your images with `example-image-a`, `example-image-b` etc. which are part of all TeX distributions. People are not all entirely enthusiastic about tangling with dropbox downloads, especially when the contents of those downloads appear to have precious little to do with your question. Make it *easy* for people to help - don't put obstacles in their way!